# Array formula basics instead of nested if-else

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have scoured the site for array formulas but am troubled by some basic issue of an array formula that i am not able to figure out.

the following table lists prices and various cutoffs for volume discounts for a product. IMO a formula like, {=IF (A2'<'Cutoff,A2*PPVM)}

in which cutoff refers to all the values and "price" refers to the price points should do the trick. I do not want to do IFS or IF-ELSE because I might want to add a row/delete a row later.

[image]

Essentially, if i have 5000 products, the price would be 5000*22.5, and so on and so forth. Can anyone suggest the basic structure of an array formula that can be used for this?

Answer (score 1):

Simmilar to PNUT's answer but yet different.  I worked on the assumption that a value at the cut off received the value of the cutoff.  ie 250 get 30 for a price.  The other thing I assumed was that quantities had to be integers.  IE you cannot sell half a nail.

I used the following formula in F3

```
=INDEX(B:B,IFERROR(MATCH(D3-1,A:A,1),1)+1)*D3
```

I used the folllowing formula in E3 just to verify what price was being pulled from the table:

```
=INDEX(B:B,IFERROR(MATCH(D3-1,A:A,1),1)+1)
```

[image: POC]

The kicker is if you have quantities greater than 22000 or the last number of your table, it will give you 0 for the price and therefore cost.

Comment: Thank you @Forward Ed, this is quite helpful. I will go figure out now why the formula doesn't work for values below the first cutoff :) 
But this definitely helps

Comment: @pnuts, Thank you for that, I wanted automatability, was not sure if I would get that using IF-ELSE in the array formula coz i tried it in my original testing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the quantity in B1 and `Cutoff` etc in A2... you could use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(B1,A:A)+1)*B1
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: why does it need the CSE?  wont it work without the CSE?

Comment: when the quantity is less than the first cutoff, formula throws an error.

Comment: Gotcha!  It has been suggest 8)

Comment: Thank you @pnuts, gave me necessary food for thought.
Forward Ed, it would work without the CSE, my main intention was to create an automated table (with ability to add/delete rows when needed) that could do these calculations.
As mentioned in my question, I did try {=IF(A4<Cutoff,A4*PPVM)}, instead of a nested if-else, or IFS or IFERROR, but I am not sure if i can get the needed automatability with those.